# Is it possible using JavaFX to have an invisible ScrollPane, but having the elements within (in my case TilePanes) fully visible?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm working on a user interface. Within an AnchorPane I have a ScrollPane that holds dynamically added TilePanes. I want the ScrollPane background to be invisible, effectively only seeing the TilePane Elements within, while I see the AnchorPane background through the gaps in between. How do I do this from the FXML?

A screenshot of my quick and dirty implementation to get a better understanding:

[image: screenshot]

I've of course tried to set the ScrollPane Background to transparent with "-fx-background-color:transparent;" but it didn't do anything. Setting its opacity to 0 makes also the elements within (TilePane) invisible.

Here the FXML:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onKeyPressed="#keyAction" prefHeight="500" prefWidth="960" style="-fx-background-image: url('file:C:/gamecenter_res/bg.jpg')" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.FXMLController">
    <children>
      <Label fx:id="txtlbl" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="387.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="800.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="200.0" onKeyPressed="#keyAction" prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="876.0">
            <content>
                <TilePane fx:id="tilePane" onKeyPressed="#keyAction" />
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
      <Label fx:id="txtlbl2" layoutX="304.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="52.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtlbl3" layoutX="424.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="52.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtlbl4" layoutX="544.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="52.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="26.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fx:id="imvwin" fitHeight="125.0" fitWidth="125.0" layoutX="795.0" layoutY="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I add lables to the TilePane within the ScrollPane that aber elements you see on the screenshot. This is the responsible method in the FXMLController class:

```
private void addTileNode(Path p) 
{
        Label l = new Label(p.getFileName().toString());
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("file:///" + p.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "//cover.jpg"));
        image.setFitHeight(166);
        image.setFitWidth(166);
        l.idProperty().set(String.valueOf(gindex));
        gindex++;
        l.setStyle("-fx-border-radius: 6;" + "-fx-border-width: 2;" + "-fx-background-color: white;"
                + "-fx-content-display: top;" + "-fx-border-color: lightblue;");
        l.setGraphic(image);
        tilePane.getChildren().add(l);

        if (selectFirst) {
            selectedLabel = l;
            selectFirst = false;
        }

        gameMap.put(Integer.valueOf(l.getId()), new Object[] { p, l });
    }
```

Comment: Odd. Setting the background color of the `TilePane` and `ScrollPane` to either `transparent` or `rgba(0,0,0,0)` has no effect. However, if you were to set a non-zero alpha channel value (`rgba(0,0,0,0.1)`, for example), you get a predictable result.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but I could be wrong. In my testing, I'm unable to make the background of **any** `Pane` truly transparent.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help at all, but a while ago I answered a question on how to create a "splash screen" by displaying a stage with a transparent pane that contained a single .png image with transparent parts. It works, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774974/showing-a-png-file-with-transparent-background-using-javafx/56776250#56776250) but I just now did a quick test and noticed that I was not able to set a background color for a specific pane, it would still always be fully transparent.

Comment: Try `.scroll-pane, .scroll-pane > .viewport { -fx-background-color: transparent; }`. It'd be easier to do this in an external CSS file.

Comment: Can I do this in the FXML instead?

Comment: It worked with the viewport solution. But how can I set the same for the TilePane in the CSS? .tile-pane doesn't work.